# Cheetah package installation error -on python 3

Tags: python, cheetah

Getting below error while installing Cheetah package (Cheetah-2.4.4) with python 3.4.3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 10, in <module>
    import SetupTools
ImportError: No module named 'SetupTools'
```

Tries many ways resolving this but no luck. Can any one pls help me what is missing here.

Comment: Cheetah hasn't seen any changes since 2011. I doubt it works on recent Python 3 releases *at all*.

Comment: Taking a second look: although some work towards Python 3 compatibility has been done, the project as it stands will not work on Python 3 at all. The `SetupTools.py` module uses syntax that will only work in Python 2, for example, and there will be more problems.

Comment: Thanks Martijn. Any alternative to the package in Python 3?

Comment: Plenty to chose from: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating. Jinja2, wheezy, moody, Chameleon, etc. etc. all support Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pip install Cheetah` for python 2.x and `pip3 install Cheetah3` for python 3.x

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed in Cheetah 3, released today. Cheetah3 works with Python 3.3+.